# Notepad++ Get only words which contains some string from a Text

Tags: notepad++, regex, search

I would like to get only words which containing specific string in notepad++ result. There are tons of examples for finding word but non oftem showing how to get only those words in result page.

For example DE2KXXXXXX -> there are different of this word (X ares different strings in text document)

So i want to get only these words not whole line. i checked everywhere and it shows only get lines which containing words or strings.

But my request is only get words containing string as start with DX2K and 6 string in word.

I just want to copy all of them to my excel. But notepad++ is getting whole line in result.

Below, X are any string maybe A-Z or 0-9 . So it will start with D and third character is 2 and 4th is K and then strings.

Example text:

> The right-click > W > T DE2K12XXXX shortcut eliminates DE2K1XX3XX the need to open Notepad first. It will create a text DE2K1XX5XX document ready for file DE2K1XXXXX naming and then all you have to do DX2K1X5XXX is hit Enter to open the text DE2K1XXX4X document for editing (hit CTRL+S to save DE2K1X2XXX your changes and you've got a very  DE2K1XX3XX streamlined text-document-creating workflow).

Notepad++ Result must be:

```
DE2K12XXXX
DE2K1XX3XX
DE2K1XX5XX
DE2K1XXXXX
DX2K1X5XXX
DE2K1XXX4X
DE2K1X2XXX
DE2K1XX3XX
```

Comment: So you want to find all instances of `DE2KXXXXXX` and save them into a new file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way:

**Step 1** : Replace all using

Search string: `(DE2K\w*)`
Replace string: `\n\1\n`

This will give the following result on your test data:

[image]

**Step 2** : Do Mark All of the same string `DE2K(\w*)` with the option
"Bookmark line", giving:

[image]

**Step 3** : Use menu *Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked Lines*, giving:

[image]

Comment: solved issue. thank you

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*?(\bDE2K\w{6}\b)(?:(?!\bDE2K\w{6}\b).)*`
- Replace with: `$1\n`  OR  `$1\r\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*?         # 0 or more any character but newline
(           # start group 1
  \b        # word boundary
  DE2K      # literally
  \w{6}     # 6 word character
  \b        # word boundary
)           # end group 1
(?:         # non capture group (Tempered greedy token)
  (?!       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    \b      # word boundary
    DE2K    # literally
    \w{6}   # 6 word character
    \b      # word boundary
  )         # end lokkahead
  .         # any character but newline
)*          # end group, may appear 0 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. DE2KXXXXXX)
\n          # line break (you may use \r\n if wanted)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
DE2K12XXXX
DE2K1XX3XX
DE2K1XX5XX
DE2K1XXXXX
DE2K1XXX4X
DE2K1X2XXX
DE2K1XX3XX
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: i could not get words as like you on my result page.

Comment: @user1070082: Strange, as shown in capture screen, it works fine. Are you doing **exactly** what I explain? What result do you get?